# How to abort an ACTION in a Dokuwiki plugin?

Tags: plugins, action, dokuwiki

I'm writing a Dokuwiki plugin to disallow a page from being edited under certain conditions. I've written a handler for `ACTION_ACT_PREPROCESS`-before to test for the condition. If the handler decides to disallow the edit, it calls `msg($errmsg, -1)`. Then I want for the page the user was browsing to remain displayed.

I've added calls to

```
$event->preventDefault();
$event->stopPropagation();
return true;
```

as exemplified in the Discussion plugin, but DW displays an editor window instead.

What should I do to basically abort the command and remain on the current page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passed data is writable. You want to switch back to the `show` action. Eg.

```
$event->data = 'show';`
```